# called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer + enums

Tags: c++, enums

Hello everyone!

I am working on this project for my school but I am having trouble putting it all together. I keep getting the error: "called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer." And I am not sure how to fix this.

My professor also wants me to use the enum that I have included in the code below and I don't even know where to start with that.

Any help at all would be awesome.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum ConvType {
    CelToFah, KelToFah, FahToCel, CelToKel, KelToCel, FahToKel, Exit,
};

ConvType menu();
double ctoF(double c);
double ktoF(double k);
double ftoC(double f);
double ctoK(double c);
double ktoC(double k);
double ftoK(double f);

int answer;
double temp;




int main() {
    ConvType menu();

}
return 0;

ConvType menu() {
    
    cout<< "Welcome to the temperature conversion program."<<endl;
    cout<< "Please enter a temperature to convert: "<<endl;
    cin >> temp;
    cout<< "Please choose an option from the menu below: "<<endl;
    cout<< "1. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n2. Kelvin to Fahrenheit \n3. Fahrenheit to Celsius \n4. Celsius to Kelvin \n5. Kelvin to Celsius \n6. Fahrenheit to Kelvin \n7. Exit."<<endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 1) {
        double ctoF(double c);
        
    }else if (answer == 2) {
        double ktoF(double k);
    }else if (answer == 3) {
        double ftoC(double f);
    }else if (answer == 4) {
        double ctoK(double c);
    }else if (answer == 5) {
        double ktoC(double k);
    }else if (answer == 6) {
        double ftoK(double f);
    }else {
        break;
    }

}

double ctoF(double c) {
    c = temp;
    double f = 9/5(c) + 32;
    cout<< c << " Celsius converted to Fahrenheit is: "<< f <<endl; 
}

double ktoF(double k) {
    k= temp;
    double f = 9/5(k - 273) + 32;
    cout<< k << " Kelvin converted to Fahrenheit is: "<< f <<endl; 

}

double ftoC(double f) {
    f = temp;
    double c = 5/9 (f - 32);
    cout<< f << " Fahrenheit converted to Celsius is: "<< c <<endl; 

}

double ctoK(double c) {
    c = temp;
    double k = c + 273;
    cout<< c << " Celsius converted to Kelvin is: "<< k <<endl; 

}

double ktoC(double k) {
    k = temp;
    double c = k - 273;
    cout<< k << " Kelvin converted to Celsius is: "<< c <<endl; 

}

double ftoK(double f) {
    f = temp;
    double k = 5/9(f-32) + 273;
    cout<< f << " Fahrenheit converted to Kelin is: "<< k <<endl; 

}
```

Comment: you put break inside menu() but break is for for/while/switch, return is for functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `9/5(c)` for example, you need to write 9 / 5 * c

also the enum is most likely meant to be used in:

```
switch(stoi(answer)) {
    case CelToFah : 
    ...
}
```